# При попытке деплоя не собирается рабочий билд

Tags: jquery, angular, развертывание, build

При попытке деплоя с помощью Bamboo не собирается стабильный билд приложения, в то же время локально проект билдиться.

```
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR! errno 1
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR! library@file:externals/patternlibrary-neogov postinstall: `ngcc`
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR! Exit status 1
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR! 
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR! Failed at the library@file:externals/patternlibrary-neogov postinstall script.
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:19    npm ERR!     C:\Users\bambbuild\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-10T11_59_19_956Z-debug.log
build   10-Mar-2022 03:59:20    
build   10-Mar-2022 03:59:20    > unified-suite@0.0.0 build-qa2 C:\Dev\Bamboo\AgentHome02\xml-data\build-dir\US-USAF1-JOB1\src\UnifiedWeb
build   10-Mar-2022 03:59:20    > C:/Dev/nodejs-15.3.0/node.exe --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=qa2 --extract-css --vendor-chunk=true
build   10-Mar-2022 03:59:20    
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js does not exist.
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    See "C:\Users\BAMBBU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-VMDEIn\angular-errors.log" for further details.
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    npm ERR! errno ENOENT
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    npm ERR! syscall spawn
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    npm ERR! unified-suite@0.0.0 build-qa2: `C:/Dev/nodejs-15.3.0/node.exe --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=qa2 --extract-css --vendor-chunk=true
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    npm ERR! 
error   10-Mar-2022 03:59:27    npm ERR! Failed at the unified-suite@0.0.0 build-qa2 script.
```

По идее ошибка в том, что нет файла node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js, но в package.json Jquery есть как зависимость [image: package.json]

При этом, если проверить наличие jquery.min.js в node_modules локально - он есть по нужному пути

Comment: А `npm install` делал перед билдом?

Comment: Да, так локально то я могу это проконтролировать. А когда CI/CD bamboo это делает перед деплоем, там нет возиожности эту проверить